# Flutter get key value from List<Class>

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a class called Products which takes in some database arguments i.e

```
this.username
```

e.t.c

Now i have a function (async)
Which returns

```
List<Products>;
```

Now when i print the response with
print i get

```
[Products(username:"username"...)]
```

I am trying to access the key username but i fail to get it.

What i have tried is only by using index

```
response[0];
```

Which gave only first list item.

How can i proceed from here to get values from the return list?

Or here is the source code

```
Future<List<Products>?> loadproducts() async {
  //this function updates the
  var db = await openDatabase('database.sqlite3');
  String create =
      "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products(uploader TEXT,item_name  TEXT,item_description   TEXT,item_price INTEGER,status  TEXT,image_url  TEXT, date TEXT, time TEXT)";
  await db.execute(create);

  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await db.query('products');
  return List.generate(maps.length, (i) {
    return Products(
      uploader: maps[i]["uploader"],
      item_name: maps[i]["item_name"],
      item_description: maps[i]["item_description"],
      item_price: maps[i]["item_price"],
      status: maps[i]["status"],
      image_url: maps[i]["image_url"],
      date: maps[i]["date"],
      time: maps[i]["time"],
    );
  });
}

class Products {
  final String uploader;
  final String item_name;
  final String item_description;
  final int item_price;
  final String status;
  final String image_url;
  final String date;
  final String time;

  Products({
    required this.uploader,
    required this.item_name,
    required this.item_description,
    required this.item_price,
    required this.status,
    required this.image_url,
    required this.date,
    required this.time,
  });

  // columns in the database.
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'uploader': uploader,
      'item_name': item_name,
      'item_description': item_description,
      'item_price': item_price,
      'status': status,
      'image_url': image_url,
      'date': date,
      'time': time,
    };
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Products{uploader: $uploader, item_description: $item_name, item_description: $item_description,item_price:$item_price,status:$status,image_url:$image_url,date:$date,time:$time}';
  }
}
```

I need help to display the data in listview builder

Comment: `response[0].username` ? I am not sure what you are trying to do? Do you want a list of all usernames for all products in the list?

Comment: A database contains many products so i want to display them.in list view builder so response[0].username returns  username not defined

Comment: I guess you are following Maximilian's udemy flutter course. right? ( He used firebase for realtime database )

Comment: Julemand101 it worked thank you but it worked when i added null check response[0]!.username